# printf equivalent for Android dev?

Tags: android

I'm just getting my toes wet.  Using Eclipse, and am not far beyond HelloAndroid.  If I have a gallery image loaded onto the screen, and I want to play around with getPixel, where do I send the resulting RGB value output so that I can read it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a:

```
private static final String TAG = "YOUR TAG";
```

Use the Log class doing:

```
Log.d(TAG, "RGB is " + rgb);
```

You can see logs with `logcat`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way would be to write:

```
Log.d(TAG, String.format("RGB is %d", rgb));
```